# Animating rows in an NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, animation, nstableview

Is there a *simple* way of animating rows in an NSTableView?

I'd like to be able to do something like *flash* a row, or fade out a row.

Essentially - to provide a bit of visual feedback when rows are added or removed.

**Edited to add:**

I'd had a quick look over Google before posting this; but I wanted to know if there was some way to do this that I'd missed other than drawing and animating parts of the table view myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To flash a row, there are a number of ways to go.  You could just grab a cell and play with it's view, such as change the color of the background or font colors.  You could also just select the cell and deselect it a few times, if you don't care about removing the existing selection from another cell.  Or you could superimpose another view on top of the cell's view and use blend modes...

For animating the deletion, you could do the same as above, dimming the cell, or even move the view up and out, transform it so it shrinks down and move it over to a trash can and shrink it all the way down as it enters the trash.  Then after the animation is done, you delete the row.